# How can I require password for some requests on node-red

Tags: node-red

I have node-red running on a raspberry pi in my house and I have several http request nodes that turn lights on and off. I have exposed these http nodes to the public internet and added a username and password to access them.

This is all great but I have a device in the house that also calls these urls (from a 192.168.1.XX IP) but it is unable to use basic authentication.

Is there a way I can require a password for non-local IP addresses and not require a password for devices on the local network?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way will be to use Apache or Nginx to proxy for Node-RED. Either of these can apply different authentication rules based on the interface/ip address that the request comes in on.

e.g. on Apache something like this:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /www/.site_htpasswd
AuthName "Protected Area"
require valid-user
Allow from 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
Satisfy Any
```